# How to have multiple arrays in python variable

Tags: python, csv

Right now I have a small script that writes and read data to a CSV file.

Brief snippet of the write function:

```
with open(filename,'w') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter=';',lineterminator='\n',)
    for a,b in my_function:
         do_things_to_get_data
         writer.writerow([tech_link, str(total), str(avg), str(unique_count)])
```

Then brief snippet of reading the file:

```
infile = open(filename,"r")

for line in infile:
    row = line.split(";")
    tech = row[0]
    total = row[1]
    average = row[2]
    days_worked = row[3]
    do_things_with_each_row_of_data
```

I'd like to just skip the CSV part all together and see if I can just hold all that data in a variable but I'm not sure what that looks like. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What does it even mean "skip the CSV part all together"? Your question is unclear and, as such, unanswerable.

Comment: I think he's saying he stores the program's state in a csv file instead of a multi-dimensional array. At least that seems to be what I'm reading. In that case, https://pythonprogramming.net/python-3-multi-dimensional-list/

Comment: malan@ is correct. There's no point in me saving data to a csv file just to read it later in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...no point in me saving data to a csv file just to read it later in the script`

Just keep it in a list of lists

```
data = []
for a,b in my_function:
     do_things_to_get_data
     data.append([tech_link, str(total), str(avg), str(unique_count)])
```

...

```
for tech, total, average, days_worked in data:
    do_things_with_each_row_of_data
```

---

It might be worth saving each *row* as a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a dictionary